# AES encrypt in cryptojs and decrypt in python Crypto.Cipher

Tags: javascript, python, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

Getting problem with encrypt using js CryptoJS and decrypt that using python crypto.Cipher

This is my implementation in js,
append iv with encrypted message and encode with base64

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
<script>
    var message='Secreat Message to Encrypt';
    var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('824601be6c2941fabe7fe256d4d5a2b7');
    var iv  = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('1011121314151617');

    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, key, { iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC });
    encrypted =encrypted.toString();


    encrypted = iv+encrypted;
    encrypted = btoa(encrypted);
    console.log('encrypted',encrypted );    
    alert(encrypted); 

   // var decrypted =  CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, { iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC });
   // console.log('decrypted', decrypted);
   //alert(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
</script>
```

And in the python script for aes encryption and decryption i used

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, random, struct
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
import base64
class AESCipher:
    def __init__(self, key):
        BS = 16
        self.pad = lambda s: s + (BS - len(s) % BS) * chr(BS - len(s) % BS)
        self.unpad = lambda s : s[0:-ord(s[-1])]
        self.key = self.pad(key[0:16])

    def encrypt(self, raw):
        raw = self.pad(raw)
        iv = "1011121314151617"
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw))

    def decrypt(self, enc):
        enc = enc.replace(' ', '+')
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        iv = enc[:16]
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return self.unpad(cipher.decrypt( enc[16:]))


def main():     

    cipher = AESCipher('824601be6c2941fabe7fe256d4d5a2b7')
    encrypteddata =cipher.encrypt(''Secreat Message to Encrypt'')
    print encrypteddata         

    decryptdata =cipher.decrypt(encrypteddata)
    print decryptdata 

main()
```

but same iv, message and key produce different encrypted message in python and js,

what is the problem with JavaScript to compatible with python decryption?

Both used AES.MODE_CBC and assume both used Pkcs7 padding. hard coded iv for now those are generate randomly

Comment: Does CryptoJS.AES.encrypt() base64 encode the output as well? Because in your js code, you are returning base64 encoded AES stuff.

Comment: append iv to CryptoJS.AES.encrypt() produce encrypted message  as iv+encrypted then do base64 encoding  as it to match python encryption "base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw))"

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the btoa() call. Hmm..

Comment: @UdayaLakmal , did you solve that? ty

Answer (score 0):

Try with an IV that has actually the same size as the block size of AES, 16 bytes. You are currently specifying 8 bytes in hexadecimals. CBC mode requires an IV of the same size as the block size and the Python API specifies (including final typo):

> For all other modes, it must be block_size bytes longs.

It's best to use a method or (predefined) constant like above.

Comment: use iv as '101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f' but when try to decrypt in python get exception "Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length" same result if iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('7061737323313233');

Comment: Does the python expect hex for the IV, or does it expect bytes? You may want to hex decode the IV (and key?) first...