# AES decrypt using python Crypto.Cipher

Tags: javascript, python, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs

I receive an encrypted response from the URL which is encrypted using CryptoJS. I plan to decrypt the response in Python using Crypto Cipher.  Here is the attached JS code which decodes the response. I tried doing  Any idea or pointers how to do it ?

Javascript :

```
function decodeResponse(result)
{    
    var keyBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("ITU2NjNhI0tOc2FmZExOTQ==");
    var iv1 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==');

    var bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(result, keyBase64, {iv: iv1}, {mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC});
    var plaintext = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    return plaintext
}
```

Python Code :

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64

def decrypt(encrypted, passphrase, iv1):
    aes = AES.new(passphrase, AES.MODE_ECB, iv1)
    return aes.decrypt(base64.b64decode(encrypted))

def main():
    message = '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'
    keyBase64 = "ITU2NjNhI0tOc2FmZExOTQ=="
    iv1 = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=='
    message = decrypt(message, keyBase64, iv1)
    print message


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I think the problem is with your IV..
Here, i have same useful links to this solution have a look at it..
[Link_1](https://gist.github.com/marcoslin/8026990) , [Link_2](https://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2016/01/29/cryptojs-pycrypto-ios-aes256.html) , [Link_3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20972851/aes-encrypt-in-cryptojs-and-decrypt-in-python-crypto-cipher) Hope this will help you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong mode of operation. You specify ECB mode in Python, while using CBC mode in JavaScript/CryptoJS.

---

Note that:

- using ECB mode, *which doesn't use an IV*, is insecure;
- using CBC mode for transport mode security is even less secure;
- using a static (or in your case, all zero) IV is not secure, commonly the IV is prefixed;
- ECB nor CBC mode provide integrity protection;
- storing keys in Strings is not very secure (generally you'd want a key store);
- passwords and keys are different things, you should not use a passphrase as a key.

---

And no, I'm not going to write the code for you. Just copying and pasting Python code here is not enough to warrant us to port the code for you.